# Random sampling from a column in a dataframe using filtering information from a different dataframe in R

Tags: r, matching

It's my first time posting a question here so if I fail to follow some guideline please let me know and I will instantly change it.

Essentially my problem is as follows: I have two datasets (lets call them dataset A and dataset B for the sake of simplicity) that are composed by a range of common columns that include socio-demographic characteristics for each individual/observation/row. What I need is for each observation/row in dataset A I have to select a random observation from dataset B that has matching characteristics regarding key socio-demographic variables. For the sake of illustration I have prepared a simple example:

```
library("dplyr")

A = data.frame(nuts2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), gender = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2))
B = data.frame(nuts2 = c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10), rep(3,10)), gender=c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)))

A <- A[sample(1:nrow(A)), ] %>% mutate(id = seq(1:nrow(A)))
B <- B[sample(1:nrow(B)), ] %>% mutate(id = seq(1:nrow(B)))
```

I am trying to avoid forloops because it seems to be considered a bad practice in R, so I have tried to create a function and use apply to run it on every observation. Assuming we wish to match a random observation ID from B with the same gender and nuts2 values as the observation in A, my code was as follows:

```
matching_fun <- function(x) {
  donor <- B %>% filter(gender == A$gender & nuts2 == A$nuts2) %>% sample_n(1) 
  donor_id <- donor$id
  return(donor_id)
}

A$donor_id <- apply(A, 1, matching_fun)
```

I would expect this to result in a dataframe containing all information that is present in A and an extra column called don_id, with the corresponding donor ID identified through random sampling by socio-demographic groups in B.

However, my code is not performing the matches accurately and is not respecting the socio-demographic characteristics. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any support/comment/critique.

**NOTE**: My datasets have close to two million observations each and I will have to use this in several tests. Consequently, computational efficiency has a certain degree of importance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach

```
setDT(A); setDT(B)
A[B, on = .(nuts2, gender)][, .(id = i.id[[sample(.N, 1L)]]), by = .(nuts2, gender)]
```

Output

```
> set.seed(1L)
> A[B, on = .(nuts2, gender)][, .(id = i.id[[sample(.N, 1L)]]), by = .(nuts2, gender)]
   nuts2 gender id
1:     1      2  1
2:     2      2 16
3:     2      1  4
4:     1      1  6
5:     3      2 25
6:     3      1 22
> A[B, on = .(nuts2, gender)][, .(id = i.id[[sample(.N, 1L)]]), by = .(nuts2, gender)]
   nuts2 gender id
1:     1      2  8
2:     2      2 10
3:     2      1 24
4:     1      1  5
5:     3      2 25
6:     3      1 29
> A[B, on = .(nuts2, gender)][, .(id = i.id[[sample(.N, 1L)]]), by = .(nuts2, gender)]
   nuts2 gender id
1:     1      2  8
2:     2      2  3
3:     2      1  4
4:     1      1 18
5:     3      2 25
6:     3      1 13
```

**Update**

I reformat the code to help you understand its logic behind.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A); setDT(B)
A[
  B, 
  on = .(nuts2, gender)
][
  , .(id = id[[1L]], donor_id = i.id[[sample(.N, 1L)]]), 
  by = .(nuts2, gender)
]
```

The output looks like this

```
   nuts2 gender id donor_id
1:     2      1  1       15
2:     1      2  2        2
3:     3      2  5        8
4:     2      2  3        6
5:     1      1  4        9
6:     3      1  6       22
```

The code above essentially works the same as this `dplyr` pipeline below, just in a more efficient way.

```
left_join(A, B, by = c("nuts2", "gender")) %>% rename(id = id.x, donor_id = id.y) %>% group_by(nuts2, gender) %>% slice_sample(n = 1L)
```

If still having trouble understanding it, then see the illustration below:

```
Let A and B be the dataframes as follows:
       A                   B
nuts2 gender id     nuts2 gender  id
    1      1  1         1      1   2
    2      1  3         1      1   7
                        2      1  13
                        2      1   4
                        2      1   6
What you want to do is:

First, match these groups
       A                   B
nuts2 gender id     nuts2 gender  id
    1      1  1         1      1   2
                        1      1   7
---------------     ----------------
    2      1  3         2      1  13
                        2      1   4
                        2      1   6

Second, slice a sample for each group in B
       A                   B
nuts2 gender id     nuts2 gender  id
    1      1  1         1      1   2
                        1      1   7 <--- RNG gives you this
---------------     ----------------
    2      1  3         2      1  13
                        2      1   4 <--- RNG gives you this
                        2      1   6 

Then, create a new variable in A with the id in B and call it donor_id
       A                            B
nuts2 gender id donor_id     nuts2 gender  id
    1      1  1        7         1      1   2
                                 1      1   7 <--- RNG gives you this
------------------------     ----------------
    2      1  3        4         2      1  13
                                 2      1   4 <--- RNG gives you this
                                 2      1   6 

However, an equivalent but more efficient way is 

First, join A and B on/by nuts2 and gender. In this way we can determine the population that we want to sample from.
       A                     B
+---------------+       +----------------+                       +----------------------+
|nuts2 gender id|       |nuts2 gender  id|                       |nuts2 gender id.A id.B|
|    1      1  1|       |    1      1   2|   by (nuts2, gender)  |    1      1    1    2|
|    2      1  3|   +   |    1      1   7|        =======>       |    1      1    1    7|
+---------------+       |    2      1  13|                       |    2      1    3   13|
                        |    2      1   4|                       |    2      1    3    4|
                        |    2      1   6|                       |    2      1    3    6|
                        +----------------+                       +----------------------+

Then, just slice a sample row within each (nuts2, gender) group and rename id.A and id.B as id and donor_id, respectively.
        A + B
               id donor_id
nuts2 gender XXXX     XXXX
    1      1    1        2
    1      1    1        7 <--- RNG gives you this
--------------------------
    2      1    3       13
    2      1    3        4 <--- RNG gives you this
    2      1    3        6
```

That's what my code does.

This part means joining A and B on each matching group of `nuts2` and `gender`.

```
A[
  B, 
  on = .(nuts2, gender)
]
```

Then,  we slice a sample row out of `.N` rows within each group of `nuts2` and `gender`. `.N` is a reserved word in the `data.table` package; it gives you the number of rows within each group. There is an `i.id` because both A and B have the column `id` and `data.table` auto renames B's `id` as `i.id` after the join. Also, we only need `id[[1L]]` because `id`s are the same within each group.

```
A[
  B, 
  on = .(nuts2, gender)
][
  , .(id = id[[1L]], donor_id = i.id[[sample(.N, 1L)]]), 
  by = .(nuts2, gender)
]
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. I have tried this code and it but I dont think i fully understand what is happening. I have edited my question so that it is more clear as to what I am looking for. For instance, for an individual in A with nuts2 == 1 and gender == 1 i need a single random donor from B with nuts2 == 1 and gender == 1. Essentially, what I would like to obtain in the end is just an extra column in A called don_id with the id information from that random draw conditional on the socio-demographic variables.

Comment: Hi @ekoam, thank you so much for the detailed explanation. This has made things more clear for me and it is working perfectly. You are the best!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid forloops, maybe if/else loops would suit for you:

```
library("dplyr")

#set.seed(1)

A = data.frame(nuts2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), gender = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2))
B = data.frame(nuts2 = c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10), rep(3,10)), gender=c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)))

A <- A[sample(1:nrow(A)), ] %>% mutate(id = seq(1:nrow(A)))
B <- B[sample(1:nrow(B)), ] %>% mutate(id = seq(1:nrow(B)))


  if (is.element(A$gender,B$gender) & is.element(A$nuts2, B$nuts2)){
  donor_id <- sample(B$id, 6)
  filter<-A[is.element(A$gender,B$gender) & is.element(A$nuts2, B$nuts2),]
  result<-cbind(filter, donor_id)[-3]
  print(result)
  }else{
  print("No matching characteristics")
}
```

Comment: Hi. First let me thank you for your reply. I have reproduced your code in my example and the matches are not working. I have edited my post so that it becomes more clear as to what I am looking for. For instance, for an individual in A with nuts2 == 1 and gender == 1 i need a single random donor from B with nuts2 == 1 and gender == 1. Essentially, what I would like to obtain in the end is just an extra column in A called don_id with the id information from that random draw conditional on the socio-demographic variables.

Comment: strange...the code is working in my IDE...maybe some packages are missing e.g. for is.element function (package "DistributionUtils")!?

Comment: Hi @RogiKo35, thank you for your reply. I didn't have the package you mentioned. Thank you for your help.